# Environmental variable as argument to a program

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, environment-variables, command-prompt

What i would like to do is run 2 simple programs called program1 an program2.What i would like to do is set the value of an environmental variable in program1 and then pass this environmental variable as argument in program2 via a cli.I am using windows 10 and these programs are written in js if this means anything.Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure this is going to be achievable if you're wanting them to run in parallel and/or check/modify variables dynamically. You should be able to have program1 start program2 with a variable though by having it exec `program2 $variable` as it's final call.

Comment: @papari : Why do you want to pass the information over the command line, if it is stored in the environment a already? Since a child process inherits the environment from its parent process, it can fetch the data directly.

Comment: @Joshua: The programs can't be run in parallel. The OP says that program1 wants to pass data to program2 via the command line. This means that program2 must be a child process of program1.